# Complex sorting over objects and their nested members using Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a Arraylist of answers, each answer contains either none or many answerValues. AnswerValues have an id.

What I would like to achieve is the following:

1. Traverse every answer and sort their answerValues by id ascending.
2. Sort answers by the smallest id of one of their answerValues.

[image]

What I've tried so far to address 2. is:

```
laneValues.setAnswers(laneValues.getAnswers().stream()
                    .sorted((e1, e2) -> e1.getAnswerValues().get(0).getId().compareTo(e2.getAnswerValues().get(0).getId())).toList());
```

Problem:

- the `.get(0)` throws an NPE if answer has no answerValues.
- Requires sorting the answerValues by their id for every answer first.

What would the ideal solution look like?

Comment: Suggestion - Write a simple custom comparator handling scenarios and then look to transform the code using functional interfaces and/or stream.

Comment: A screenshot of your debugger is not sufficient to describe your software. Regarding the things you wrote beneath it, if `.get(0)` throws an NPE when there are no values, it implies that your method returns `null` instead of an empty list. You should fix that immediately. But to handle empty lists while sorting, you have to define a policy first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have found a suitable solution for my problem now. But I have separated the sorting into three steps:

First thing I did is to sort the answerValues by ID:

```
for (SrmQsRfiAnswer answer: laneValues.getAnswers()) {
    List <SrmQsRfiAnswerValue> answerValues = answer.getAnswerValues();
    answerValues.sort(Comparator.comparingLong(SrmQsRfiAnswerValue::getId));
}
```

Now all answerValues of every answer are sorted by ID. Then I put all answers to a HashMap with the answer ID as key.

```
Map <Long, List< SrmQsRfiAnswer>> answerMap = laneValues.getAnswers().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SrmQsRfiAnswer::getId));
```

And in the final step, I sort the answers for each key in the Map by the lowest ID of the answerValues with a custom "comparator":

```
answerMap.values().forEach(listOfAnswers - > listOfAnswers.sort(Comparator.comparingLong(SrmQsRfiAnswer::getMinAnswerValueId)));

public class SrmQsRfiAnswer {
...
    public Long getMinAnswerValueId() {
        if (answerValues == null || answerValues.isEmpty()) {
            return Long.MAX_VALUE; // Return a high value for null or empty lists
        }
        return answerValues.stream()
            .mapToLong(SrmQsRfiAnswerValue::getId)
            .min()
            .orElse(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```